# Getting an error when trying to delete YouTube video comments using Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Getting the following error when trying to delete YouTube comments using Python. I can retrieve and set the moderation status of comments, but can't delete comments. Can't figure this out.

```
def deleteComments(service):
    request = service.comments().delete(id="Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg, 2CUswqQvx9q8MllybCuBF4AaABAg")
    request.execute()
```

Error message:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg%2CUswqQvx9q8MllybCuBF4AaABAg returned "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.">
```

---

Update:
The following code sample approved a comment, but generated an error message when trying to delete another comment. As suggested by @stvar, I added an exception to handle the error and retry the command after a brief delay to no avail. Not sure what else to do.

Code sample:

```
request = service.comments().setModerationStatus(
    id="UgyVOfo6iFZPZ-lye9V4AaABAg",
    moderationStatus=status
)
request.execute()    
print("Approved comment "+"UgyVOfo6iFZPZ-lye9V4AaABAg")

i = 4
while True:
    try:
        request = service.comments().delete(
            id="UgyVOfo6iFZPZ-lye9V4AaABAg"
        )
        request.execute()
        print("Deleted comment "+"UgyVOfo6iFZPZ-lye9V4AaABAg")
        break
    except:
        if (i>8):
            break
        time.sleep(i) 
        i=i+2
        print("retry after 2 seconds")
```

Output:

```
Approved comment Ugys7LJAAAqXjruiM0h4AaABAg
retry after 2 seconds
retry after 2 seconds
retry after 2 seconds
```

Comment: Tried the following :

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your comment ID

```
Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg, 2CUswqQvx9q8MllybCuBF4AaABAg
```

is invalid for some reason? The IDs I recently saw were of the following format:

```
^U[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{25}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{22})?$
```

---

If you try to delete multiple comments in one shot, note that, according to [the docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete#id), the parameter `id` does not support a comma-separated list of IDs, as some other API endpoints do:

> **id** (string)
> The id parameter specifies the comment ID for the resource that is being deleted.

In such case, you'll have to issue separate calls to `Comments.delete` endpoint for each of your comments you need deleted.

---

Also note that the ID you pass to the API (the one I quoted above) is not the same as the one embedded within the error message you have shown:

```
Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg,UswqQvx9q8MllybCuBF4AaABAg
```

This may indicate that the culprit for your error is not the API!

---

Note that you may remove only the comments that you've written yourself; that is that you cannot remove other people's comments.

Indeed this behavior of the API *is not documented as such officially*. But Google's staff mentioned that *to be working as intended* on [Dec 6, 2016 00:24 UTC](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35178140#comment2). A more recent mention is from [Jun 15, 2019 22:33 UTC](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134801181#comment2).

Comment: Thank you. Before posting, I tried deleting one comment by specifying one id, but strangely, I was getting the same error message.

Comment: Here's what I got when trying to delete one comment:

googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id= Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg returned "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the request's input is invalid.">

Comment: In case of a transient error reported by the API, you should employ an exponential back-off algorithm that retries to delete the same comment multiple times. Something like: try delete, if transient error then sleep `4 secs`, try delete, if transient error then sleep `16 secs` (i.e. `4^2 secs`),  and so on.

Comment: For sake of completion, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#comments_youtube.comments.delete) is the official doc describing the `Comments.delete` errors one may encounter. In your case above, it was an error of kind `processingFailure`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using curl, but was not successful because of issues getting an access token. I ended up just setting the moderation status of the comment to rejected. It's unfortunate that deleting comments using Python does not work for me. Maybe something is wrong on YouTube's end. Thank you.

Comment: Note that you may remove only the comments that you've written yourself; that is that you cannot remove other people's comments.

Comment: For what concerns `curl`, just issue a command like the following: `curl -X DELETE -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token' 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg'`, where `access_token` is a valid (i.e. non-expired) [access token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#http-get-examples).

Comment: The API also accepts access tokens as URI parameters: `curl -X DELETE "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?id=Ugzl8ec3rKxt6ClZlSR4AaABAg&access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN"`

Comment: Here is [detailed doc](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps#offline) showing how to obtain a fresh access token from the API; the `curl` call would look like: `curl -o access_token.json "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?client_id=$CLIENT_ID&client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET&refresh_token=$REFRESH_TOKEN&grant_type=refresh_token"`

Comment: @stvar Many thanks. I looked at the docs, but it didn't mention that only my comments can be deleted using the delete method. I want to delete comments that are held for review. I can do that using the GUI, so I should be able to do it using The API. Additionally, the error message talks about invalid input as a possible reason for the error. Anyway, if I can't delete comments made by other users on my channel, at least I can reject comments, which means the rejected comments won't appear in the Held for Review list.

Comment: @stvar. Thank you for the cURL information. Will give it a try.

Comment: Indeed this behavior of the API *is not documented as such officially*. But Google's staff mentioned that *to be working as intended* on [Dec 6, 2016 02:24AM](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35178140). A more recent mention is from [Jun 15, 2019 01:33AM](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134801181).